# does qtquick have a function such as wait()?

Tags: qt, qml

Is there something like a wait() function for qtquick? I have as mousearea that calls an animation and a different state. When you click the mousearea they are both fired at the same time I need the state change to fire after the animation is completed.

```
            MouseArea {
              id: movie_mouse_mm
              x: 392
              y: 364
              width: 104
              height: 100
              onClicked:{
                image6.state = "rotated"
                page.state = 'State1'
                Logic.get_db(5,0);
                        }
                     }
```

So I need to get

```
page.state ='state'
```

to run after

```
image6.state= "rotated"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use transitions & animations like that:

```
Item {
    //...
    MouseArea {
       //...
       onClicked:{
           parent.state = "rotate"
           //...
       }
    }
    transitions: [
        Transition {
            to: "rotate"
            SequentialAnimation {
                RotationAnimation { target: image6; duration: 1000; direction: RotationAnimation.Clockwise }
                PropertyAction { target: page; property: "state"; value: "state" }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can adjust `duration`

More information [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-animation-transition.html).